# How to limit queryset/the records to view in Django admin site?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

By default Django admin site shows all records of a related model/table for viewing. How can I show only the records that meet certain criteria?

Comment: Do you mean by default, or do you just want that option to be available from the changelist page?

Comment: By default. Whenever I load the page, it shows only records that mean some requirements. Those requirements can be changed in the back-end.

Comment: And also, how to make those to show up in the changelist page?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In your admin definition, you can define a `queryset()` method that returns the queryset for that model's admin. eg:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

Then only objects with `user=request.user` will be visible in the admin.

Comment: +1 I'm so happy to see this and it turned out to be so simple! Thanks!

Comment: But in this way, it's not possible to get additional queries for other users if you'd want to search for that. So it doesn't answer the question the way I read it.

Comment: Since Django 1.6 `queryset` has been replaced by `get_queryset`

Answer (score 10):

I know this has an "accepted answer", but I just wanted to throw this out there since I came across this answer while pursuing something else and realized I had an alternative solution that I found and use often that gives me more granular level control than the accepted answer.

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "FIELD":
            kwargs["queryset"] = TestModel.objects.filter(test=False)
        return super(TestAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "FIELDS":
            kwargs["queryset"] = TestModel.objects.filter(test=False)
        return super(TestAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: See what happened there! His answer was good..... yours was better. Sterling work.

Comment: This is a lot cleaner solution. Thank you!