# Django - Limit the entries in models.ForeignKey()

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

```
class UserCustomer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(CustomerProfile)
```

In admin interface, while adding a new record, is it possible to restrict(remove) the 'user' in user drop down, if that user is already associated with any customer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to limit queryset/the records to view in Django admin site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279313/how-to-limit-queryset-the-records-to-view-in-django-admin-site)

Comment: @Ignacio Is it possible to restrict while adding new record?

Comment: tried [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279313/how-to-limit-queryset-the-records-to-view-in-django-admin-site) answer your question?

---

[How about this one?](http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/filtering-dropdown-lists-in-the-django-admin) He goes through multiple examples including filtering ModelAdmin inlines (which I think is what you're after).

Comment: No. Question is specific to addtion of new record. Not in display list. Any sugesstions?

Comment: @siva If it's not in the drop down list in the admin site, it can't be used for an insert, can it?