# How can I make Django use select_related() on a foreign key in the admin site?

Tags: django

I have a couple of models: `Review`, which has fields for album reviews, `Record`, which is an album's name etc, and `Band`, which is a band's name. `Record` has a foreign key against `Band` and `Review` has a foreign key against `Record`.

In the admin forms for `Review` I want to show a dropdown select box for all `Record`s. At the moment, the unicode method for `Record` is just:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.record_name
```

This isn't very helpful so I changed it to this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.band.band_name + ' - ' + self.record_name
```

This now adds a query for each `Record` (3000 or so), obviously not good.

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279313/how-to-limit-queryset-the-records-to-view-in-django-admin-site), I tried adding this to my model admin for `Record`:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    return super(RecordAdmin, self).queryset(request).select_related('band')
```

This didn't make any difference, though.

Is it possible to use foreign key fields in the `__unicode__` representation of a model without incurring n-squared queries?

UPDATE: here's the models (with unrelated fields removed):

```
class Review(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        # this is used in other places where we show review titles
        return self.record.band.band_name + ' - ' + self.record.record_name

    record = models.ForeignKey('Record')
    review_text = models.TextField()

class Record(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        # this generates a billion queries
        #return self.record_name
        return self.band.band_name + ' - ' + self.record_name  

    def band_and_title(self):
        return self.band.band_name + ' - ' + self.record_name

    band = models.ForeignKey('Band')
    label = models.ForeignKey('Label')
    record_name = models.CharField(max_length=175)

class Band(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.band_name

    band_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Do you have more information: Django version etc.  I'm using almost exactly this code in several places and projects with great success.

Comment: Sure: version 1.4.1 locally (although server is using 1.2.3).

Am I putting it on the right model? Technically I'm editing a `Review` not a `Record`, but I tried it there too and didn't see any difference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject the `select_related` at the time that the admin site creates the change form. You can do this by overriding [`ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) for your ModelAdmin. Something like this:

```
class ReviewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "record":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Record.objects.all().select_related()

        return super(ReviewAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(
            db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: weird. formfield_for_foreignkey does not fire up at all. I'm using django 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment you may actually need to select related both the record and *its* band.  Like this:

```
class ReviewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Review
    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(ReviewAdmin, self).queryset(request).select_related('record', 'record__band')

class RecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Record
    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(RecordAdmin, self).queryset(request).select_related('band')
```

Using the [Django Toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar) is a good way to discover what queries are being run.

Comment: Thanks -- this didn't make any difference, sadly :( -- was a bit unsure about the `model = mymodels.Review` line, is this a "magic" variable (since it's not referenced anywhere else in this code?). I just used `model = Review` (I already import `webzine.models.Review` above this).

Comment: It's a style thing,  I always import just the models.  Shouldn't matter. Can you add the stripped down objects to your question.  Like I said, this works and we're just missing something.